# High precision binary multiplication

Tags: binary, computer-science, multiplication

Assume I want to multiply **1.1** and **1.4** in binary. I store them as **11/10** and **14/10** respectively. The result is **1.54** which I must store as **154/100**. But I have 4 bits to store numerator that is why I must cut the result down to **15/10** so 15 would fit my memory limitations.

I could use double memory buffer to temporarily store 154 in 8 bits and then repeatedly divide it by 10 until it would fit, but it would be slow to calculate partial products and then have long division to divide it by 10. I also could cut multipliers so their product would fit but this causes major loss of accuracy. So seems like I need something else to multiply numbers like that, and I cannot find the solution.

Which ways can be used to solve this memory+accuracy problem?

Comment: What, exactly, is your question.  And why do you ask "high precision binary multiplication" and then proceed to perform base-10 calculations?

Comment: My question is how I can divide two numbers in binary avoiding extending memory limits and precision errors?